# List or Tuple for throwaway iterables

Tags: python, list, tuples

Certain Python builtins, such as `any` and `all`, require an iterable argument. A common pattern I encounter with these is that I chain creating the iterable with the function call. For example:

```
locations = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
if any(["city" in location for location in locations]):
    print("Locations includes a city")
```

Is there any benefit to doing this with a tuple instead...

```
locations = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
if any(("city" in location for location in locations)):
    print("Locations includes a city")
```

...in terms of memory usage or execution time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a tuple; it's a generator expression. And there is a very big benefit: the generator expression only produces values as `any` requests them, while the list comprehension has to produce a full list of values before `any` can start iterating over it.  Consider the following:

```
if any(["city" in location for location in ["city", "country", "county", "state"]):
```

The list comprehension has to build `[True, False, False, False]` before `any` can start iterating, and of course the last three `False` values are irrelevant, because `any` will return as soon as it sees the first `True`. Compare to

```
if any(("city" in location for location in ["city", "country", "county", "state"])):
```

in which case *only* `"city" in "city"` will be computed before `any` sees `True` and returns, without every having to make the other three comparisons.

When the generator expression is the *only* argument to a function, you can omit the surrounding parentheses:

```
if any("city" in location for location in locations):
```